# Discord Bot outputting nothing client.on('ready')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically, when I run `node .` in my command prompt nothing is outputted.

My code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});
//My key is located here but I've taken it out for obvious reasons
client.login = "key";
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
client.login = ('key');
```

If that is how your code looks and isn't just a typo in the question, that is invalid syntax. `client.login()` is a method. This is how it should look:

```js
client.login('key');
```

That is most likely your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your following code contains false syntax.

```
client.login = "key" //Will create errors.
client.login("key") //Will not create errors.
```

Also, I would recommend you to install `dotenv` from the npm package database.
Its safer and barely needs any coding experience.

Just look at the difference

```
client.login("key") //Can see your token
require('dotenv').config();
client.login(process.env.key) //Cant see your token unless i see your .env
```

Just simply install the package running `npm i dotenv`, then create a file `.env` and inside that file have your enviromental variables.

```
key = token
```

I hope this helped you. Oh also if your bot is on GitHub make sure to add a `.gitignore` file so it cant be accessed by other users.

```
//.gitignore file

.env //This is the file you want hidden
```